# JDBC+SSL: Bundling a CA cert, client cert and client into a single keystore file

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc, keytool

Google Cloud SQL supports SSL connections by generating a server `ca-cert.pem`, a `client-cert.pem`, and a `client-key.pem` for you.  I've managed to get my Java client connecting to Cloud SQL with the following steps:

1) Import the server CA certificate into a truststore file:

```
keytool -import -alias mysqlServerCACert -file ca-cert.pem -keystore truststore
```

2) Bundle the client cert and client key together into a pkcs12 file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem -inkey client-key.pem -out client.p12 -name clientalias -CAfile ca-cert.pem
```

3) Import the pkcs12 into a keystore file:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass keystore -destkeystore keystore -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass keystore -alias clientalias
```

4) Tell the JVM to use my truststore and keystore:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/my/keystore \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keystore \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/my/truststore \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=truststore
```

This all works, but unfortunately it precludes outbound HTTPS connections from other client libraries -- in my case, the Firebase java client library.  The problem is that my `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` argument has overridden the default `cacerts` file bundled with the JDK.

I seem to have two options.  One option, non-ideal, is to import my server CA certificate into the JDK's `cacerts` file, on every production and development machine, using OS-specific and JDK-version-specific commands.  This option seems unwieldy for a real production setup.

The other option is to bundle my server CA cert and client cert into a single (local) trust chain, which Java would then use to validate my client key.  I'm pretty sure it's possible, from what I've read, but I don't know the required incantation.

My guess is that I should use a single `openssl` command to create a pkcs12 bundle containing my server CA cert, client cert, and client key in the correct order, and then use `keytool` to import that into a new keystore.  I would omit the `-D.../trustStore` JVM parameters and only specify the keystore parameters.  Java would use the local CA trust chain for my Cloud SQL client key, but would fall back to the global `cacerts` file for all other SSL negotiation.

Is this possible?  If not directly possible as a single pkcs12, then is there some other set of steps that will get them all into a single keystore, bypassing the need for the truststore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the default JRE `cacerts` file to a new truststore and add the server certificate to that. Use for all clients. Make this a build step and repeat every time the JRE is upgraded, so you don't miss certificate changes in the default `cacerts.`

Of course if the server certificate is properly signed by a recognized CA, it isn't necessary to import it anywhere, or to use a custom truststore. And if it isn't signed by a recognized CA it should be.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'll definitely use this as a fallback if nothing else works.  I'll also talk to the Cloud SQL team about getting their certs signed properly.

Comment: I talked to a security guy today and he made the same recommendation.  Accepting your answer.

Comment: Update:  this solution worked for me, and was really easy.  Thanks again!